# How can I retrieve x from this Ax=b?

Tags: matlab, matrix-inverse

I'm studying inverse problem, and I tried to inverse the matrix A, but it has 'rank deficient'.
The matrix A is non-square matrix too.
So, I tried b times `pinv(A)`, but it yielded not correct solution.

I want to know the method or function that can solve this problem.

This is the MATLAB code

```
vertical = eye(20);
A=zeros(10,200);
for j=0:9;
    A(j+1,1+20*j:20*j+20)=1;
end

for j=0:9;
    A(11:30,1+20*j:20*j+20)=vertical;
    
end

b=[0 4 4 4 10 10 4 4 4 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 2 2 2 8 8 2 2 2 0];
x=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
   0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
```

Comment: In your script `A`, `x` and `b` are given. What exactly do you want to calculate? `A` is a 30x200 matrix, `b` is a 1x30 vector. There is no `x` with `Ax=b`.

Comment: @m2016b please don’t change the code style in questions. Spaces around operators are a personal choice, we typically don’t force people here to do that one way or another.

Comment: Given the sizes of A and b, it looks like you have Ax=b' (with the single quote representing the transpose). In MATLAB you’d do `x = A \ b.'`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Oh, sorry, I miss the transpose.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix and vector aren't the right dimensions so it won't work. `pinv(A)` in Matlab has a parameter called tolerance that truncates the singular values after some epsilon. You can use the truncated SVD this way to solve and you will get an approximation. The condition number is inf so first correct your script then set the tolerance to `10^(-13)` or something.

Comment: Thanks. I think that can't totally retrieve x.

Comment: @Park Supposing they were the right dimensions then it would. The other poster mentioned the backslash operator x = A\b' would in general be better. If you read this

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/how-does-the-matlab-backslash-operator-solve-ax-b-for-square-matrices

It is in general going to be faster because it takes into consideration the structure of the matrix. In this case since it's ill conditioned and non-square it'd probably use the SVD anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should have is

```
x = pinv(A)*b'
```

since 'b' is of size `1x30` while `A` is of size `30x200`

---

To verify the result, you can try

```
>> A*(pinv(A)*b')-b'
ans =

  -9.4369e-16
   1.7764e-15
  -3.5527e-15
            0
  -8.8818e-15
   3.5527e-15
   8.8818e-16
   3.5527e-15
  -2.6645e-15
  -2.2204e-16
  -6.6613e-16
   8.8818e-16
            0
   4.4409e-16
   8.8818e-16
  -2.4425e-15
   1.3323e-15
  -8.8818e-16
   2.2204e-15
  -1.4988e-15
  -3.3029e-15
  -4.4409e-16
            0
   3.5527e-15
            0
            0
  -3.7748e-15
  -2.4425e-15
  -8.8818e-16
   3.0531e-16
```

Comment: Sorry, this is bad advice. The correct way to solve for x is `x = A \ b.'`. This can be significantly more precise and robust, and is also computationally more efficient.